# Passing on IP camera through raspberry pi

Tags: linux, routes, camera, ip, raspberry-pi

I've been having problems with a project of mine. I had a raspberry pi connected to webcams but I found that this was too much load for the RPI. This is why I decided to purchase and use an IP camera. The only problem though, is that the IP camera does not get wifi reception where the it should be placed but I have a powerful Directional antenna which I can attach to the RPI. I want the RPI to route internet traffic from the camera plugged into ethernet, over the wifi. I'm not one hundred percent sure how to do this but so far I have giving the wifi priority over the Ethernet and set up a dhcp server so that the camera gets an ip address.

In my current setup, when I am hard-wired into the Raspberry pi, I can connect to the camera (on 192.168.2.10) but outside, I can only connect to the web server which is also running on on the RPI. I'm not sure if the port forwarding of the camera works but I want to be able to access the webserver on 192.168.1.117 (this works) and I want to see the camera on 192.168.1.117:10 (this does not work). To try to do this, [I followed this tutorial but I cant seem to get any results after finishing it.](http://rbnrpi.wordpress.com/project-list/wifi-to-ethernet-adapter-for-an-ethernet-ready-tv/)

Any help is greatly appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `UV4L` with the [mjpegstream driver](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=13). It turns your IP camera into a (virtual) Video device available on your RPi. An example is [here](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=16#example5) (in step 3 pass the URL of your IP camera stream).